# PowerShell script takes days to finish

Tags: powershell

The following script runs great except for the fact that it takes days to finish. Does anyone have any tweaks or tips to cut down the execution time?

The shared directory, Images\Equipment, contains over 5500 folders is grows daily.

```
# If the Admin folder for Equipment Images does not exist, make a new one and set the correct permissions.
$Location = "E:\Images\Equipment\*\"
$file = "E:\Images\Equipment\*\Admin"
foreach ($_ in (Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\*\)){if(($_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.name -eq "Admin")-eq $false)    
   {
        New-Item -Path $location -Name "Admin" -ItemType directory
        $errorActionPreference = "continue"}}
$folder = "E:\Images\Equipment\*\Admin"
Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\ -Directory -Filter "admin" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

  $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName

if ($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected) { $acl.Access | % {$acl.purgeaccessrules($_.IdentityReference)} }
else {
        $isProtected = $true 
        $preserveInheritance = $false
        $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($isProtected, $preserveInheritance) 
     }
$account="recoequip\folder sales group"
$rights=[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$inheritance=[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
$propagation=[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$allowdeny=[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

$dirACE=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($account,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation,$allowdeny)
$ACL.AddAccessRule($dirACE)

Set-Acl -aclobject $ACL -Path $folder
Write-Host $folder Permissions added}
```

Thank you for any assistance.
Sara

Comment: You're question is very hard to answer without knowhing what the "goal" of your script is. And what did you try to find out where the bottleneck in your script is? Did you run the debugger to see which step takes a long time to finnish?

Comment: One thing you can do to help speed that up is not keep re-creating the same ACL over and over again.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? What optimizations can be done depends on what version you run.

Comment: The "goal" of my script is to add the Admin folder if it doesn't exist setting the correct permissions. If the Admin folder does exist I want to make sure the permissions are set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to try and speed up your script I would create the ACE once at the beginning as suggested by mjolinor in his comment above. I would not bother looking for folders that are missing an Admin subfolder, and just create the Admin sub-folder in each folder regardless, and use the `-force` argument. That won't delete and re-create, but what it will do is return a folder object for each folder even if it already existed. Collect all those folders in a variable. Then iterate through those folders and apply the correct permissions for them.

```
# If the Admin folder for Equipment Images does not exist, make a new one and set the correct permissions.

#Define ACE to apply
$account="recoequip\folder sales group"
$rights=[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$inheritance=[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
$propagation=[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$allowdeny=[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$dirACE=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($account,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation,$allowdeny)

#Make sure all Equipment Images folders have an 'Admin' subfolder, and store the folder objects for later
$Folders = Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\* -Directory | %{New-Item -Path ($_.FullName + "\Admin") -ItemType directory -ErrorAction Continue -Force}

ForEach($Folder in $Folders){

    $acl = Get-Acl $Folder.FullName

    if ($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected) { $acl.Access | % {$acl.purgeaccessrules($_.IdentityReference)} }
    else {
        $isProtected = $true 
        $preserveInheritance = $false
        $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($isProtected, $preserveInheritance) 
     }

    $ACL.AddAccessRule($dirACE)

    Set-Acl -aclobject $ACL -Path $folder
    Write-Host $folder Permissions added
}
```

This does assume that you are using PSv3 or better and have access to the `-Directory` switch for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. If you do not have v3 installed I would suggest upgrading your version of PowerShell. I realize that's not always an option so alternatively you can change line 12 to this:

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\* -Attributes Directory | %{New-Item -Path ($_.FullName + "\Admin") -ItemType directory -ErrorAction Continue -Force}
```

or

```
    $Folders = Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\* | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | %{New-Item -Path ($_.FullName + "\Admin") -ItemType directory -ErrorAction Continue -Force}
```

If you have to use one of these I would suggest the first one since that filters for only directories at the FileSystem Provider level, instead of returning all folders and files, and then making PowerShell filter out the files.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried running your script and it does not create the Admin folder if it does not exist.

Comment: Does it give you an error or something? Because it works fine on my end when I tested that part of it.

Comment: This is the error it gives repeatedly in between assigning permissions to certain Admin folders. See answer section. Also, it does not assign permission to Admin folders already created that the permissions are currently not correct on.

Comment: Huh, I had `$acl = get-acl $_.fullname` which kind of works, but I changed it to `$acl = get-acl $folder.fullname` which is what I intended to start with. That should work better for you.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much MadTechnician. Your new script runs in minutes versus mine that took days! MadPowerShellGenuis more like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This was to long to add in a comment.
This is the error it gives repeatedly in between assigning permissions to certain Admin folders.

Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.
At line:15 char:20
+     $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:21 char:9
+         $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($isProtected, $preserveInheritance)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:24 char:5
+     $ACL.AddAccessRule($dirACE)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Set-Acl : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AclObject' because it is null.
At line:26 char:24
+     Set-Acl -aclobject $ACL -Path $folder
+                        ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand